# Python: Allow certain methods to be called if a certain attribute is true

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to guard the use of certain methods in a class against misuse. I think a guard decorator could work as below.

For example, we have class `Hello`. It has an attribute `allowed` and two methods `allowed_function` and `disallowed_function`. The guard decorator would manage what functions can and can't be called.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowed = True

    def guard_func(self):
        return(self.allowed)

    @guard(guard_func)
    def allowed_function(self):
        print "I'm allowed!"

    @guard(not guard_func)
    def disallowed_function(self):
        print "I'm not allowed!"
```

How should I go about this in Python?

Comment: Do you mean for the decorator to work per instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation of `guard` for Python 3 (it looks like you might be using 2; I highly recommend upgrading).

```
import functools


class NotAllowed(Exception):
    pass


def guard(condition):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not condition(self):
                raise NotAllowed(f"Not allowed to call {func}")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowed = True

    def guard_func(self):
        return self.allowed

    @guard(guard_func)
    def allowed_function(self):
        print("I'm allowed!")

    @guard(lambda self: not self.guard_func())
    def disallowed_function(self):
        print("I'm not allowed!")


h = Hello()

h.allowed_function()      # will print the message
h.disallowed_function()   # will raise a `NotAllowed` exception
```

Basically, you need two levels of indirection here. You have to write a function which returns the actual decorator function, so that you can parameterize it based on the condition function you pass in when you actually use the decorator. You also need to be careful about how `self` gets passed around.

---

`functools.wraps` is not necessary, but highly advised: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Everything above should work as advertised on Python 2, you just need to replace the f-string with a string format.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the `guard` decorator by @JoshKarpel seems just fine.

However, I would suggest changing your design slightly:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.group1_enable = True
        self.group2_enable = False

    def group1(self):
        return(self.group1_enable)
    def group2(self):
        return(self.group2_enable)

    @guard(group1)
    def allowed_function(self):
        print "I'm allowed!"

    @guard(group2)
    def disallowed_function(self):
        print "I'm not allowed!"
```

This design allows groups of functions to be independently enabled and disabled.